# Android Responsive design using android studio

Tags: android-layout

***Hi all*** !!

I'm newbie to android, Can i get any solutions to make my android app layout that fits in all screens.

If there is any tutorial on it, that would be appreciated !!

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is too broad. Any tutorial or book that teaches you about layout in Android teaches you to design flexible layout for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the following folders in res and add the xml in that

```
res/layout-small
res/layout-normal
res/layout-large
res/layout-xlarge
```

And open it from studio layout and make changes.
this [link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The Android resource system gives you the tools to provide alternate resources based on the available width, height, or smallest width — important measurements that serve as the basis for choosing when to change our UI based on the space available.
Width and Breakpoints

Width is perhaps the most important dimension when it comes to choosing when to change your UI. This is because width is the basis for the breakpoint system.

A very good example is [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-responsive-ui-in-android-7dc7e4efcbb3#.d3btpmzlf)

Comment: @PradeepKumar hope this link will help, accept if woked. :P